# Filter by userId

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to filter a list of posts and a list comments by userId. Am passing the userId params as postCreator and commentCreator. What am I doing wrong?

```js
//data type for comments 
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {comment: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "comment can not be empty"],
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now(),
    },
    vote: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1,
    },
    commentCreator: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: [true, "comment must belong to a user."],
    },
    postCommentedOn: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "Post",
      required: [true, "a comment must belong to a post"],
    }, } )
 
 //data type for post is
    
    const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    postContent: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Post Content cannot be empty"],
    },
    postTitle: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Post Title cannot be empty"],
    },
    vote: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now(),
    },
    postCreator: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: [true, "a post must belong to a user."],
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
    },
  },)
```

I need to filter a list of posts and a list comments by userId. Am passing the userId params as postCreator and commentCreator. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let filter = {};
if (req.params.postId || req.params.userId)
  filter = {
    postCommentedOn: req.params.postId,
    postCreator: req.params.userId,
    commentCreator: req.params.userId,
  };
```

Comment: Tell us more. We would need to see what you then do with the filter, and what happens.

Comment: Is the filter being used in MongoDB?
If so can you post the datatype of those keys.
Because if they are of type ObjectId, you need to wrap those userId using ObjectId() to convert them.

Comment: @djna, sure. With the filter am able to  use a url like api/v1/users/userId/posts to get all posts by a particular user if I remove the commentCreator in my code snippet above. My url return null when my code is as is now with the postCreator and commentCreator

Comment: @PromodKumar, yes its MongoDB. I edited my questions and adde the data type

Comment: @Francis thanks for the update, I have replied in answers section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the data type, I can see postCommentedOn, postCreator, commentCreator
are of type ObjectID meanwhile, req.params are received in string format.
So you need to convert them to ObjectId to be used in the filter.

Something like the below code should help.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
 filter = {
    postCommentedOn: ObjectId(req.params.postId),
    postCreator: ObjectId(req.params.userId),
    commentCreator: ObjectId(req.params.userId),
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just asked your question to the OpenAI JavaScript Codex. It returned a result which I don't know if it really works or not. But  I want to see if this actually works or not.

```
/* I need to filter a list of posts and a list comments by userId. Am passing the userId params as postCreator and commentCreator */
var posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Post 1',
    body: 'Post 1 body',
    userId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Post 2',
    body: 'Post 2 body',
    userId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Post 3',
    body: 'Post 3 body',
    userId: 1
  }
];
var comments = [
  {
    id: 1,
    body: 'Comment 1',
    userId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    body: 'Comment 2',
    userId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    body: 'Comment 3',
    userId: 1
  }
];
var postCreator = 1;
var commentCreator = 1;
var filteredPosts = posts.filter(function(post) {
  return post.userId === postCreator;
});
var filteredComments = comments.filter(function(comment) {
  return comment.userId === commentCreator;
});
console.log(filteredPosts);
console.log(filteredComments);
```

Please forgive me if this doesn't work. And if it does let me know.
Thanks.